# Continous fadein and fadeout effect in css

Tags: html, css, fadein

I want a fadein and fadeout effect in CSS which should not stop (should be continous).
I created one: http://jsfiddle.net/z5UB5/

Code :

CSS:

```
body { background: #fff; }

@-webkit-keyframes 'blink' {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
.objblink {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: blink;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="objblink">TEST</p>
```

But this code is only working in Google Chrome. I want that it should also work in other major browsers.

Comment: `-webkit-keyframes` - That will only work on browsers using the webkit engine.

Comment: @NickR I tried the -moz and -o too but didn't work :(

Comment: Also you have webkit-animation defined, which tells it to run the animation (named blink) in webkit browsers, but you don't have anything else (FF/IE etc) - have a look at http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: @user3816402: “ I tried the -moz and -o too but didn't work :(” — if you don’t include that code, and explain what you mean by “didn’t work”, then we’re :( too.

Comment: @user3816402 If you r using jquery use this code     setInterval(function(){
$(".objblink").fadeToggle();
    },500);
    }); =====link (http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/z5UB5/2/) ====Work in all browser

Comment: Ok, Here's a jsfiddle in which i added the -moz too but it's still not working in Mozilla : http://jsfiddle.net/vrA7x/

Comment: I have given my answer with your latest fiddle. check it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can see my modification here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5UB5/5/), i make your animation definition more short :

```
-moz-animation: blink 2s ease-in-out infinite normal;
-webkit-animation: blink 2s ease-in-out infinite normal;  
animation: blink 2s ease-in-out infinite normal;
```

Add `-moz` and `@keyframes` syntax and removed single quotes from blink.
You can see shorthand syntax of animation [at Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

Comment: Thanks adding -o and -ms will make it work in Opera & IE too?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to a jQuery solution, this should do the trick for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    shown = true;
    setInterval(function(){
        if(shown == true)
            $(".objblink").fadeOut();
        else
            $(".objblink").fadeIn();

        shown = !shown;
    },500);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/phDtL/) is the JSFiddle

Comment: Yea i know it can be done through jQuery but it will be not supported in every browser. Right? + CSS will load faster :(

Comment: Well, it depends which browsers you need to support. It is supported in Chrome, Firefox and IE 9+. To have it supported on IE8 is needed just a little fix. CSS loading is surely faster (even though it's less than a second), but the actual processing effort is very similar...

Answer (score 0):

As your latest fiddle, you have declare the animation name with single quote. Remove that one and it will work.

Instead of this

```
@-moz-keyframes 'blink' {
0% {
    opacity:1;
}
50% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
}
```

Use this

```
@-moz-keyframes blink {
0% {
    opacity:1;
}
50% {
    opacity:0;
}
100% {
    opacity:1;
}
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrA7x/1/)

Comment: Thanks adding -o and -ms will make it work in Opera & IE too?

Answer (score 0):

```
CSS:
.objblink{
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 3s;
    animation:myfirst 3s;
 }
@keyframes myfirst {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
HTML:
<p class="objblink">TEST<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" /></p>
```